# Dynamic Navigation bar (with images) with jquery and php - problems with mouseover effects

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, navigation

I'm building a dynamic navigation bar which is controlled by PHP, and I'm using images within my list. And I'm applying jQuery for the 'hover' effects. This is the PHP code:

```
$path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$page = basename($path);
$page = basename($path, '.php');
```

And in my navigation list I'm setting 'display:none' and 'display:inline' depending on the return value of $page using a PHP 'if' statement. See code:

```
<ul id="cssdropdown">
  <li class="headlink">
  <a class="lightNav" href="index.php"  <?php if($page == 'index'){echo "style='display:none !important'";}else{echo "style='display:inline'";}?>><img src="images/navButtons/home.png" /></a>
  <a class="darkNav" href="index.php" <?php if($page == 'index'){echo "style='display:inline !important'";}else{echo "style='display:none'";}?>><img src="images/navButtons/home-dark.png" /></a>
  </li>....
```

This is all working fine, the display of the Nav bar images change depending on what page the user is at. But my problem is now I'm trying to integrate jQuery to get a nice 'mouseover / hover' effect. See jQuery code:

```
$("li.headlink").hover(function(){
  $(this).find("a.lightNav").css("display", "none");
  $(this).find("a.darkNav").css("display", "inline");
},function(){
  $(this).find("a.lightNav").css("display", "inline");
  $(this).find("a.darkNav").css("display", "none");
});
```

But this is causing problems. When the user moves the cursor over the image in the Nav bar for the current page (ie the 'dark' image), it removes the display attribute set by PHP (obviously).

So I need a way to check on mouseover if 'darkNav' has display 'inline' or 'none' and tailor my jQuery from there, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do, I'm not the worlds greatest javascript/jQuery coder. Is there a way to check if an element has a particular CSS property applied to it, I googled and fiddled with my code for hours, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance everyone.

P.S. I added the CSS !important in my nav bar within the PHP if statement, but this for some strange reason, is only working in Chrome, all other browsers are ignoring this rule.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can check an attribute value like this:

... your code...

```
  alert($(this).find("a.lightNav").css("display"))
```

As far as using jQuery to hide/show elements, simply use:

```
  $(this).find("a.lightNav").hide()
  $(this).find("a.darkNav").show()
```

No need to fiddle with "display", it's already built-into `hide()/show()`. You should not need use this either:

```
style='display:inline !important'"
```

By default the display is already `block` or `inline`, so unless you're using "display:none" you can usually lave these out.

If you have a left-floating menu you should be using `float:left`, not `display:inline`

Also inline styles override stylesheet CSS, so you should never need to use `!important`.

One hint at styling menus, style the A-tag, not the LI. Put the events on the A tags, not the LIs.

If you want to learn how to style menus properly, see my tutorial:
[**I love lists**](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/).

Answer (score 0):

> "So I need a way to check on mouseover if 'darkNav' has display 'inline' or 'none'.."

This is untested but you could try something like...

```
   if ($(this).attr('style') == "display:none") {
     // do something
   }
   else if ($(this).attr('style') == "display:inline") {
     // do something
   }
```

However, you may want to try addClass() and removeClass() instead of changing and/or using inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

yep..i'd second that using addClass()l and removeClass() would be loads better...some code like

```
if($(this).hasClass('visible') {
  // do something
}
else {
  // do something else
}
```

seems far better and professional and readable...but just me saying...